# Why flatten isn't working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, flatten

I have read the code in how to flatten an array in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control) in JS. And works fine, but I don't understand why isn't working in this case:

```
const data = [null, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
const flattened = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if(null != cur)
        acc.concat(cur)
}, [])
```

And this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
```

How to correct this?

Comment: If the purpose is to filter null values (or false values maybe?) out, you could also do that early one by using Array#sort: `data.filter(cur => cur !== null).reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), []);`

Comment: @naomik While the subject matter is addressed at linked Question, the specific issue at Question is not addressed by an Answer at linked Question. Is there a Question/Answer addressing no value being returned from `Array.prototype.reduce()` callback function?

Comment: @thibmaek I wanted to iterate only once over the array, that's why I choose just the reduce. If I had used a filter before it would iterate over again by the reduce method.

Answer (score 4):

No value is returned from function passed to `.reduce()`

```js
const data = [null, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
const flattened = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (cur !== null)
          acc = acc.concat(cur);
        return acc   
}, []);

console.log(flattened);
```

Comment: @LucasAlmeidaCarotta Also `acc.concat(cur)` should be `acc = acc.concat(cur)` or `acc.push(...cur)`